# Java - JOGL deploy: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jogl

Dev env: ItelliJ 14 -> compiles and runs fine.

When executing my custom created .jar from command line this appears

```
C:\Java\Projects\OpenGLES\out\artifacts\Test1>java -jar Test1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/G
ventListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

I'm trying to create .jar artifact, that I could just double click start.
I think that the problem means that this class cannot find some resources. The JOGL/JogAmp official sites gives explanation on deployment of .jars with JOGL, but I think that I missed something.

The Test1.jar has following structure:

```
Test1.jar/
--com/
----company/
------Main.class
--jar/
----gluegen-rt.jar
----gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
----gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar
----jogl-all.jar
----jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar
----jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar
--lib/
----windows-amd64/
-------gluegen-rt.dll
-------joal.dll
-------jocl.dll
-------jogl_cg.dll
-------jogl_deskop.dll
-------jogl_mobile.dll
-------nativewindow_awt.dll
-------nativewindow_win32.dll
-------newt.dll
-------soft_oal.dll
--META-INF/
----MANIFEST.MF
--com
--jar
--lib
--META-INF
```

manifest.mf contains -

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.Main
```

Comment: It's obviously incomplete. How is Java intended to guess that your JAR contains some JARs with such a manifest?

Comment: You must follow this layout if you want to give a chance to GlueGen to find the native libraries at runtime: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Usage Your current layout is plain wrong. I advise you to make a fat JAR, rather use jogamp-fat.jar (available since the version 2.3.2 of JOGL) during the merge, preserve the layout as much as possible if you don't want any trouble. You duplicate the native libraries, it's totally useless.

Comment: I advise you to read my paragraph about executable JARs concerning its cons: http://tinyurl.com/pavgbgs

Answer (score 0):

By the stack trace it seems that the JVM cannot find the class com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener that means it can't resolve the path to the included jar files. The path of the jar files is not correct. Follow the link to see how to package jars correctly.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: Is it possible that I supply correct path to jar with GLEventListener, but inside GLEventListener is referenced another jar that is missing and this error is thrown?

Comment: In that case you need to look into the full stack trace carefully.

Comment: Rest of stack trace is redundant as I suppose? I rather think that solution is in missing jar or bad path. The folder structure is really strict in case of JOGL. Just an idea .....

Comment: It's not really a problem with JOGL, your approach is just extremely naive, you put your native libraries and your JARs into a JAR but you give no mean to the JVM to know where to find them, it's not magic. JogAmp isn't to blame.